# How do you execute a method only if another one has been run?

Tags: c#, methods, switch-statement

I have a choice for the user in Main using a switch. Depending on what the user chooses, several choices later, the program will either end or not. At least, that is what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
//This is in Main
string[] menyVal2 = new string[] {"Go to the hotel room", "Go to the dining hall"};
            string title2 = "text";
            int choice2 = menu(menuChoice2, title2);

            switch (choice2)
            {
                case 0:
                    hotelRoom();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    diningHall();
                    break;
            }
```

Many lines of code later...

```
public static void save()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            string[] menuChoice = {"Chapter 2", "Back to start"};
            string title = "text";

            int choice = menu(menuChoice, title);
            switch (val)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (hotelRoom = true) //this if-statement does not work
                    {
                        withoutCross();
                    }
                    else if (diningHall = true)
                    {
                        withCross();
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Main(new string[] { });
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: so what _is_ the problem?

Comment: When I understand your title of the question correctly, then is this a solution: Make the return type of the method bool and fill it to a variable. Later you can check if the variable is true. And execute the other method.

Comment: so which code you refer to as the switch to either stop or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand your title of the question correctly, then this is a solution:

Make the return type of the method bool and fill it to a variable.

```
bool isMethodExecuted = MyMethod();
```

Later you can check with a if-Statement, if the method is executed:

```
if(isMethodExecuted)
    MyOtherMethod();
```